# How to get the color of a pixel in an UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, colors, pixel

I am trying to develop a small application. In it, I need to detect the color of a pixel within an UIView. I have a CGPoint defining the pixel I need. The colors of the UIView are changed using CoreAnimation.

I know there are some complex ways to extract color information from UIImages. However I couldn't find a solution for UIViews.

In Pseudo-Code I am looking for something like

```
pixel = [view getPixelAtPoint:myPoint];
UIColor *mycolor = [pixel getColor];
```

Any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a (fast) solution?

Comment: Using the bitmap context turned out to be fast enough for my purposes. Give it a try and see how it works for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is pretty horrible and slow. Basically you create a bitmap context with a backing store you allocate so you can read the memory, then you render the views layer in the context and read the appropriate point in ram.

If you know how to do it for an image already you can do something like this:

```
- (UIImage *)imageForView:(UIView *)view {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
  [view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *retval = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(void);
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return retval;
}
```

And then you will get an image where you can get the pixel data. I am sure the mechanism you have for dealing with images involves rendering them into a context anyway, so you can merge that with this and factor out the actual image creation. So if you take that could and remove the bit where you load the image and replace it with the context render:

```
[view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

you should be good.

Answer (score 81):

Here is more efficient solution:

```
// UIView+ColorOfPoint.h
@interface UIView (ColorOfPoint)
- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end

// UIView+ColorOfPoint.m
#import "UIView+ColorOfPoint.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (ColorOfPoint)

- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //NSLog(@"pixel: %d %d %d %d", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

    return color;
}

@end
```

Link to files: https://github.com/ivanzoid/ikit/tree/master/UIView+ColorOfPoint

Comment: Warning in .m, removed with `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: It looks like you are rendering just a single pixel.  Very cool.

Comment: Can this code be modified to work out the color of a whole row of pixels?

Comment: Could you explain CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);?

Comment: Just a comment, this is only "more efficient" if your renderInContext isn't particularly expensive. If you're eg. rendering from a PDF then caching an image and testing that will be more efficient.

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira the CGContextTranslate moves the potential pixel to position 0,0 so that it will be the only pixel rendered

Comment: cast to `(CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst` to remove compile warning

Comment: @ivanzoid I've added a swift translation. Feel free to copy

Comment: Hi I'm trying to do the same but its picked color with some mixing with the background color, even if I have set the background to nill, how can I remove blending? I have tried all the mode available  context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.), can you check, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192147/color-picking-color-is-not-exact-after-picking-getting-some-black-channel-or-a

Answer (score 27):

A swift'ified version of **ivanzoid**'s answer

**Swift 3**

```
extension CALayer {

    func colorOfPoint(point:CGPoint) -> CGColor {

        var pixel: [CUnsignedChar] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

        let context = CGContext(data: &pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

        context!.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)

        self.render(in: context!)

        let red: CGFloat   = CGFloat(pixel[0]) / 255.0
        let green: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixel[1]) / 255.0
        let blue: CGFloat  = CGFloat(pixel[2]) / 255.0
        let alpha: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixel[3]) / 255.0

        let color = UIColor(red:red, green: green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)

        return color.cgColor
    }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
extension CALayer {

    func colorOfPoint(point:CGPoint)->CGColorRef
    {
        var pixel:[CUnsignedChar] = [0,0,0,0]

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(&pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y)

        self.renderInContext(context!)

        let red:CGFloat = CGFloat(pixel[0])/255.0
        let green:CGFloat = CGFloat(pixel[1])/255.0
        let blue:CGFloat = CGFloat(pixel[2])/255.0
        let alpha:CGFloat = CGFloat(pixel[3])/255.0

        let color = UIColor(red:red, green: green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)

        return color.CGColor
    }

}
```

based around the underlying `CALayer` but easily translatable back to `UIView`.

Comment: i tried to use it but it returns just zeros. so i always get white color. unfortunately my programming skills are not so advanced to find out myself. thank you

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4** & **4.2**. Tested with XCode 10, iOS 12, Simulator & iPhone 6+ Running iOS 12.1.

This code work fine.

```
extension UIView {
    func colorOfPoint(point: CGPoint) -> UIColor {
        let colorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

        var pixelData: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        let context = CGContext(data: &pixelData, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

        context!.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)

        self.layer.render(in: context!)

        let red: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixelData[0]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let green: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixelData[1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let blue: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixelData[2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let alpha: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixelData[3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        let color: UIColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)

        return color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed some minor errors

```
- (UIImage *)imageForView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *retval = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return retval;
}
```

Also, add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

to your file to avoid warning messages.

Combining your code with the code found [here](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/) works flawlessly.

Comment: Why does it look like you simply copied Louis's code and removed the superfluous "void" in the call to `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`?

Comment: That is what I did. What is a better way to handle corrections on here?