# How to get the color of Touched Area in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

Can anybody know how to get touch color of `UIView` ? When I touch on a view then I want the color which is on touched area of the view.
Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can use this open source [**library**](https://github.com/ivanzoid/ikit/tree/master/UIView+ColorOfPoint) for doing this.
It's a category of `UIView` with additional features.

After adding this you can get the color like:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    NSLog("%@",[self colorOfPoint:[touch locationInView:self]]);
}
```

Also check [**iPhone UIImage Pixel Color**](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/)

Here is a link to another thread in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160229/how-to-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-an-uiview)