# iPhone : How to get colour of each pixel of an image?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I want to get color of all the individual pixels of an image. 
**To elaborate**
Let say I have an image named "SampleImage" having 400 x 400 pixels
Basically I want to create a grid from 'SampleImage' which will have 400 x 400 squares each filled with color corresponding to the specific pixel in 'SampleImage'.

I know this is a little abstract, but I am novice in iOS and don't know where to start from. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160229/how-to-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-an-uiview possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked flawlessly for me -:

```
    - (NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count:(int)count{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < count ; ++ii)
    {
        CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        byteIndex += 4;

        UIColor *acolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
        [result addObject:acolor];
    }

    free(rawData);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this :
Here is more efficient solution:

```
// UIView+ColorOfPoint.h
@interface UIView (ColorOfPoint)
- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end

// UIView+ColorOfPoint.m
#import "UIView+ColorOfPoint.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (ColorOfPoint)

- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //NSLog(@"pixel: %d %d %d %d", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

    return color;
}

@end
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Nishant and borrrden!
@Nishant : Where I have to specify the image from which I have to pick the colors ?
Do I have to call this method again and again for every pixel or there is a shorthand for it as borrrden mentioned ?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you are a novice, you should consider doing something easier first.  Anyway, what you need to do is set up a `CGContextRef` via `CGBitmapContextCreate` with enough data to hold your image.  Once you create it, you need to render your image into it via `CGDrawImage`.  After that you will have a pointer to every pixel in your image.  The code is similar to Nishant's answer, but instead of 1x1, you will use 400x400 to get all of the pixels at once.