# How to calculate number of black colored CGPoint in a view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alpha, cgpoint

I have some difficulties in Swift, Xcode
I have drawn UIView which has transparent background and I need to calculate the percentage of drawn area in UIView, any ideas?
I only know the way by reviewing each cgpoint and getting the value of alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to do this :

1. Go through the each pixel of the UIView
2. calculate colour of that pixel
3. Then compare that colour to Black colour 
   Here is the example for retrieving the colour from the pixel :
   [How to get the color of a pixel in an UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160229/how-to-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-an-uiview)

Comment: Thanks, I was planning to do the same, but I have around 100 Views, it may take quite long, what do you think?

Comment: cant say actual . But depends on processor . But you really have 100 views ? that means 100 screens ?

Comment: Yes, I have 100 pages of pdf file